# Error: Invalid hook call while using MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Material Table in the Admin Panel, inside the Dashboard component the invalid hook call error is coming when i am using the Material Table, and without material the app is running  fine.
What i want is to fetch the feedback data from the Firebase and show the data into the material table.
The problem is the error is showing because of the material table but i cannnot understand how it is an invalid hook call. Am i using the material in a wrong way or missing something?, please guide me through this.

```
    Here is the Dashboard Component code:

    import React from 'react';
    import AdminNavbar from '../../layout/AdminNavbar';
    import SideMenu from '../../layout/SideMenu';
    import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
    const Dashboard = () => {
        const tableCol = [
            {
                title: "Name", field: "name"
            },
            {
                title: "Course", field: "course"
            },
            {
                title: "Email", field: "email"
            },
            {
                title: "Phone", field: "phone"
            },
            {
                title: "Submitted at", field: "submit"
            }
        ];
        const tableData=[
            {
                name: "Wasim",
                course: "Web Master",
                email: "wasim@gmail.com",
                phone: 9716689303,
                submit:"01/12/2021",
                feedback:"There should be more doubt sessions."            
            },
            {
                name: "Rachna",
                course: "Graphic Master",
                email: "rachna@gmail.com",
                phone: 9547183456,
                submit:"04/12/2021",
                feedback:"More Activities"            
            }
        ];
    
        return (
            <>
                <SideMenu/>
                <AdminNavbar />
                <div className="table-div">
                     <MaterialTable title={"Student's Feedback"}
                        data={tableData}
                        columns={tableCol}
                        options={{
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#01579b',
                                color: '#FFF'
                            },
                            exportButton: true,
                            selection: false,
                            search: true
                        }}
                        detailPanel={[
                            {
                                
                                tooltip: 'Show Feedback',
                                render: rowData => {
                                    return (
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                textAlign: 'center',
                                                color: 'black',
                                                backgroundColor: '#eaeef3',
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {rowData.feedback}
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                },
                            }]}
                    />
                 </div>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Dashboard;
```

Inside the admin navbar i have just the logo and the user initials.
Then Admin Navbar code is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppBar,  Grid, IconButton, Toolbar } from '@material-ui/core';
import logo from "../../images/admec-logo.jpg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {  PowerSettingsNew } from '@material-ui/icons'

 class AdminNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <AppBar position="static" />
                 <Toolbar className="nav-head">
                <Grid container alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item  >
                        <Link to='/admin/dashboard' className='center'>
                            <img className='headerLogo' src={logo} alt='logo' />
                        </Link>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item sm></Grid>
                    <Grid item >
                        <div className='user-img btn btn-floating pink lighten-2'>MW</div>
                         <IconButton>
                            <PowerSettingsNew />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Toolbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default AdminNavbar;
```